# Render Edit form for nested attributes via ajax (with image upload via jquery-fileupload)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, jquery-file-upload

I have 2 models:

1. Building → `has_many :building_views`
2. BuildingView → `belongs_to :building`

I can create BuildingView only for existing Building — via Edit form of Building.
BuildingView have `image` and `title` attributes. Image is uploading via Carrierwave.
Workflow:

1. I go to edit page of Building
2. There I have `file_field` that allow choose multiple files
3. I choose few images and they uploading via `jquery-fileupload-rails` gem (creating BuildingView for each image)
4. Right after upload they appear in the Edit form (without reloading page) with thumb and input field to edit title of BuildingView

1, 2 and 3 are ok. Images are uploading, BuildingView are creating and after page reload they appear in the Edit form of Building with title edit input field (which also can be successfully edited). The problem with 4: I can't append BuildingView edit forms via ajax.

Here is my files:

**controllers/admin/buildings_controller.rb**

```
# other defs ...

def edit
  @building = Building.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @building = Building.find(params[:id])
    if @building.update_attributes(building_params)
      flash[:success] = 'Woohoo!'
      redirect_to admin_buildings_url
    else
      render :edit
    end
end

# other defs ...

private
  def building_params
    params.require(:building).permit(:all_building_params,
                                      building_views_attributes: [
                                        :_destroy,
                                        :id,
                                        :building_id,
                                        :image,
                                        :title
                                      ])
  end
```

**views/admin/buildings/edit.html.haml**

```
%h1 Edit building
= form_for [:admin, @building] do |f|
  = render 'admin/buildings/form', f: f
  .form-element-container
    .form-element.b-form-labels &nbsp;
    .form-element.b-form-fields
      = f.submit 'Edit building'
      = link_to t('admin.cancel'), :back

= form_for [:admin, BuildingView.new] do |f_bv|
  = f_bv.hidden_field :building_id, value: @building.id
  = f_bv.file_field :image, multiple: true, name: 'building_view[image]'
```

**views/admin/buildings/_form.html.haml**

```
// fields for Building...

#building_views
  .form-element-container
    .form-element
      %h2 Building views

= f.fields_for :building_views do |bv_form|
  = render 'admin/buildings/form_building_views', f: bv_form
```

**views/admin/buildings/_form_building_views.html.haml**

```
.form-element-container
  .form-element.b-form-labels Image:
  .form-element.b-form-fields= image_tag(f.object.image_url(:thumb)) if f.object.image

.form-element-container
  .form-element.b-form-labels Title:
  .form-element.b-form-fields= f.text_field :title
```

**assets/javascript/admin/buildings.js.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
  $('#building_view_image').fileupload(
    dataType: 'script'
  )
```

**controllers/admin/building_views_controller.rb**

```
class Admin::BuildingViewsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @building_view = BuildingView.create(building_view_params)
  end

  private

    def building_view_params
      params.require(:building_view).permit(:building_id, :image)
    end

end
```

**views/admin/building_views/create.js.haml**

```
- if @building_view.new_record?
  == alert('Oops!');
- else
  == $('#building_views').append('#{j render('admin/buildings/form_building_views')}');
```

I choose files to upload → error from console:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#<Class:0x007ffaa52faad8>:0x007ffaa7393970>):
```

So I need to pass `f`, when I'm rendering edit form in **views/admin/building_views/create.js.haml**.
But I can't figure out how. I tried:

```
j render('admin/buildings/form_building_views', f: @building_view)
```

but:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `object' for #<BuildingView:0x007ffaa738a348>):
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I can see, I can't pass this `f` to this partial. So I recreated partial manually.

**views/admin/buildings/_form_building_views_ajax.html.haml**

```
.form-element-container
  .form-element.b-form-labels= image_tag(@building_view.image_url(:thumb)) if @building_view

  .form-element.b-form-fields= text_field_tag "building[building_views_attributes][#{building_nested_model_count(@building_view, @building)}][title]", nil, placeholder: 'Title'

= hidden_field_tag "building[building_views_attributes][#{building_nested_model_count(@building_view, @building)}][id]", @building_view.id
```

I just recreated form, which rails generate with the `fields_for` helper.
There's new helper there: `building_nested_model_count(@building_view, @building)` — it counts the amount of `BuildingViews` for current `Building`. I will use it for `params` hash (see `id` and `name` input field params).

I need to update 3 files.

1. Define @building

**controllers/admin/building_views_controller.rb**

```
class Admin::BuildingViewsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @building_view = BuildingView.create(building_view_params)
    @building = @building_view.building
  end

  private

    def building_view_params
      params.require(:building_view).permit(:building_id, :image)
    end

end
```

1. Add `building_nested_model_count` helper

**helpers/admin/building_views_helper.rb**

```
module Admin::BuildingsHelper

    def building_nested_model_count(nested_var, building)
        nested_class = nested_var.class
        nested_class.where(building_id: building.id).count
    end

end
```

1. And switch partial for ajax render

**views/admin/building_views/create.js.haml**

```
- if @building_view.new_record?
  == alert('Oops!');
- else
  == $('#building_views').append('#{j render('admin/buildings/form_building_views_ajax')}');
```

I don't know is it good or bad way to solve this, but it works: form for new `BuildingView` is rendering, and its `title` saving to db after form submit.